# Is that possible to use checkbox and EditText to calculate?

Tags: android

I am trying to using the checkbox and the EditText to do the calculation. While I had use the code:

```
        int myNum = Integer.valueOf(commericalvalue.getText().toString()).intValue();
        total = myNum+total;
```

To do the calculation it works fine, however when it combine with checkbox the App had crashed.
The below is the code for my activity file.

```
package com.kenrick.userinterface;


import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class sll_enquires_totalresult extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sll_enquires_totalresult);

        final EditText commericalvalue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3) ;

        Button Sum_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);

        final CheckBox booking = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_booking);
        final CheckBox commerical = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_commerical);
        final CheckBox cert = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_cert);
        final CheckBox license = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_license);
        final CheckBox agency = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_agency);
        final CheckBox importdec = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_importdec);
        final CheckBox exportdec = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_exportdec);
        final CheckBox local = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_local);
        final CheckBox translation = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_translation);
        final CheckBox po = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_po);

        Sum_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int total=0;
                int myNum = Integer.valueOf(commericalvalue.getText().toString()).intValue();
                total = myNum+total;

                if(booking.isChecked()){
                    total+=1;
                }
                if(commerical.isChecked()){
                    total+=2;
                }
                if(cert.isChecked()){
                    total+=3;
                }
                if(license.isChecked()){
                    total+=4;
                }
                if(agency.isChecked()){
                    total+=5;
                }
                if(importdec.isChecked()){
                    total+=6;
                }
                if(exportdec.isChecked()){
                    total+=7;
                }
                if(local.isChecked()){
                    total+=8;
                }
                if(translation.isChecked()){
                    total+=9;
                }
                if(po.isChecked()){
                    total+=10;
                }

                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(sll_enquires_totalresult.this).create();
                alert.setTitle("Total Price:");
                alert.setMessage("The total price is HKD$ "+total);
                alert.show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It take me a long time to find the solution and I still cannot fix it up to now. Can someone able to give me some suggestion. I will be really thankful.

The below is the activity_sll_enquires_totalresult.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".sll_enquires_totalresult">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trade Processing Credit Service" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text=" " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Commodities" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text=" " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Commerical Value" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text=" " />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_booking"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Booking Condition Fee" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_booking"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_commerical"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Commerical Documentation" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_commerical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_cert"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Certificate of Origin" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_cert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_license"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="License Application" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_license"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_agency"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Importer/Exporter Agency" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_agency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_importdec"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Import Custom Declaration" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_importdec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_exportdec"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Export Custom Delcaration" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_exportdec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_local"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Local Trade Regulatory" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_local"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_translation"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Translation Service" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_translation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_po"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="PO Management" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox_po"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=" " />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat

```
08-02 00:38:30.034 26082-26082/? I/l.userinterfac: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-02 00:38:30.285 26082-26082/? W/l.userinterfac: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-02 00:38:30.646 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface W/l.userinterfac: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
08-02 00:38:30.647 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface I/chatty: uid=10088(com.kenrick.userinterface) identical 10 lines
08-02 00:38:30.648 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface W/l.userinterfac: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
08-02 00:38:30.670 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-02 00:38:30.826 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface W/l.userinterfac: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
08-02 00:38:30.939 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
08-02 00:38:31.017 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
08-02 00:38:31.017 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-02 00:38:31.017 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-02 00:38:31.018 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-02 00:38:31.018 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-02 00:38:31.050 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xde80a580: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
08-02 00:38:31.079 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde80a580: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xde838b70)
08-02 00:38:31.090 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
    glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
08-02 00:38:31.149 26082-26113/com.kenrick.userinterface D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xde80a580: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xde838b70)
08-02 00:38:32.918 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: StudioProfilers agent attached.
08-02 00:38:33.002 26082-26154/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
08-02 00:38:33.095 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
08-02 00:38:33.096 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface W/l.userinterfac: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
08-02 00:38:33.359 26082-26082/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Memory control stream started.
08-02 00:38:33.850 26082-26158/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking disabled.
08-02 00:38:33.853 26082-26158/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking enabled.
    JNIEnv not attached
08-02 00:38:34.197 26082-26158/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 11092
08-02 00:38:34.401 26082-26158/com.kenrick.userinterface V/StudioProfiler: Tracking initialization took: 547717370ns
```

Comment: Let us see activity_sll_enquires_totalresult.xml and the crash log

Comment: I think this might crash when EditText is empty and Submit button is pressed. Anyway, added log doesn't show anything. We need to show the excepton that is thrown when it crashes. Something like "NullpointerException" for example.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I think the crash is not because the EditText is empty. Since each times I will type in the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) in your activity's `xml` put this line for `EditText3`:  
`android:inputType="number"`   
so that the user inputs only integers

2) in your listener replace this line:

```
int myNum = Integer.valueOf(commericalvalue.getText().toString()).intValue();
```

with this:

```
int myNum = Integer.valueOf(commericalvalue.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: May I ask what is the different of 2)?

Comment: For some reason I did not understand exactly the string returned included spaces, that;s why I used trim()